# debug Intranet ASP.NET Applications for Safari

Tags: safari, cross-browser

I have an asp.net intranet application for booking jobs and a phone index. Now most of my users are fine as they are using Firefox and or Internet Explorer. I have a user who can only use Safari and for some reason when we navigate to the intranet app, Safari seems to do a lot of loading then finally says; "Safari could not open the page “http://mywebserver/” because the server is not responding."

Although the short answer is to get the user to use another browser, as a programmer, I am interested into why this is the case in the first place and what I can do now, and in the future, to detect and where necessary redirect so that my asp.net applications can also run in Safari.

I am also interested if anyone has any suggestions as to how I can go about getting this asp.net application to run for this user, in Safari. We have tried navigating to the site using machine name and IP address and still get the same response.

Many thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using ISA Server and user impersonation in the ASP.Net application? I've seen issues where safari crashes if you try to authenticate through ISA Server.

Ensure that local addresses are bypassing the proxy, that may resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm I am bypassing the proxy for local addresses on the machine and we are using ISA Server and user impersonation in the ASP.Net application. Is there something specific I should be checking here?

Comment: I dont think theres a workaround for ISA server causing the issue. try tracert'ing to the intranet to ensure that the proxy server is bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for this, after running tracert it came back straight away, but listed FQDN of machine.network.local. When navigating using this its running exactly as intended. Marked as correct answer, thanks for your support.